# Arch Linux: PyCharm doesn't use Jetbrains Platform

Tags: linux, jvm, pycharm, archlinux

I wanted to use the Jetbrains Mono Font with ligatures in PyCharm. The settings dialog says that I have to use the Jetbrains Platform to see ligatures, so I tried to enable it.

I've downloaded the "Choose Runtime" plugin. When I select `jbsdk11b96_linux_x64.tar.gz` and click "Install" it downloads it to `~/.PyCharmCE2019.2/config/jdks/jbsdk11b96_linux_x64` and restarts PyCharm. The file `~/.PyCharmCE2019.2/config/pycharm.jdk` now contains the correct path. But the About dialog of PyCharm still says "VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corpration" and ligatures are still not working.

I tried to install the AUR `jetbrains-jre` and use it with the same effect.

Comment: Do you have IDEA_JDK environment variable specified? As described in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/switching-boot-jdk.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch on Pycharm (works like IntelliJ)

See this: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under